# PhpStorm Debugger extension is not detected while using with PHPUnit

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PHPUnit through PhpStorm with a remote interpreter from docker.
The Container is run through `docker-compose`

PHPUnit works. Xdebug works through the browser. In `docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini`, I have all the mandatory options, and I can see in the `CLI Interpreter Config` that PhpStorm does load this config.

BUT when I try to run PHPUnit with the debugger I get:

> PhpStorm Debugger extension is not detected

[image: PhpStorm Debugger extension is not detected]

**CLI Interpreter Config:**

[image: CLI Interpreter Config]

**DockerFile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

# OS DEPENDENCIES
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache bash git curl libmcrypt libmcrypt-dev openssh-client icu-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache libxml2-dev freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev zip libzip-dev g++ make autoconf
RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev
RUN docker-php-source extract
RUN pecl install xdebug redis
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis
RUN docker-php-source delete
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pgsql
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_pgsql
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap intl zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache

# XDEBUG CONFIGURATION
ARG XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST
ARG XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT
ARG XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK
ARG XDEBUG_INI=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN echo "error_reporting = E_ALL" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "display_startup_errors=1" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "display_errors=1" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "xdebug.profiler_enable=1" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=$XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "xdebug.idekey=\"PHPSTORM\"" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_port=$XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_host=$XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> ${XDEBUG_INI}

# COMPOSER INSTALLATION
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# EXORT COMPOSER GLOBAL PATH
ENV PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin" #edited
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
  dataapi:
    container_name: dataapi
    build:
      context: ${DOCKER_FILES_PATH}/privateapi/
      args:
        - XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT=10000
        - XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=172.17.0.1 #DOCKER network IP
        - XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK=0  #edited
    command: sh -c "composer install && bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --allow-no-migration -n && php-fpm"
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the result of phpinto() in phpunit:

```
sodium

sodium support => enabled
libsodium headers version => 1.0.18
libsodium library version => 1.0.18

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.32.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlite3.defensive => 1 => 1
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.exception => 0 => 0
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_hosts => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form= => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
unserialize_max_depth => 4096 => 4096
url_rewriter.hosts => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => form= => form=
user_agent => no value => no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.9.6
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

Debugger => enabled
IDE Key => PHPSTORM

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => On => On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_host => 172.17.0.1 => 172.17.0.1
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 10000 => 10000
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.10

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching => Disabled
Optimization => Disabled
SHM Cache => Enabled
File Cache => Disabled
Startup Failed => Opcode Caching is disabled for CLI

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename => no value => no value
opcache.consistency_checks => 0 => 0
opcache.dups_fix => Off => Off
opcache.enable => On => On
opcache.enable_cli => Off => Off
opcache.enable_file_override => Off => Off
opcache.error_log => no value => no value
opcache.file_cache => no value => no value
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks => On => On
opcache.file_cache_only => Off => Off
opcache.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
opcache.force_restart_timeout => 180 => 180
opcache.huge_code_pages => Off => Off
opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 8 => 8
opcache.lockfile_path => /tmp => /tmp
opcache.log_verbosity_level => 1 => 1
opcache.max_accelerated_files => 10000 => 10000
opcache.max_file_size => 0 => 0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage => 5 => 5
opcache.memory_consumption => 128 => 128
opcache.opt_debug_level => 0 => 0
opcache.optimization_level => 0 => 0x7FFEBFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model => no value => no value
opcache.preload => no value => no value
opcache.preload_user => no value => no value
opcache.protect_memory => Off => Off
opcache.restrict_api => no value => no value
opcache.revalidate_freq => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.save_comments => On => On
opcache.use_cwd => On => On
opcache.validate_permission => Off => Off
opcache.validate_root => Off => Off
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On

zip

Zip => enabled
Zip version => 1.15.6
Libzip headers version => 1.6.1
Libzip library version => 1.6.1

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.11
Linked Version => 1.2.11

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable => Value
PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/.composer/vendor/bin
HOSTNAME => fb6d372627df
JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN => 1
IDE_PHPUNIT_PHPUNIT_PHAR => /var/www/privateapi/vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-7.5-0/phpunit
IDE_PHPUNIT_VERSION => 7.5.20
PHPIZE_DEPS => autoconf         dpkg-dev dpkg       file        g++         gcc         libc-dev        make        pkgconf         re2c
PHP_INI_DIR => /usr/local/etc/php
PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS => --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --disable-cgi
PHP_CFLAGS => -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
PHP_CPPFLAGS => -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
PHP_LDFLAGS => -Wl,-O1 -pie
GPG_KEYS => 42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312
PHP_VERSION => 7.4.7
PHP_URL => https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.7.tar.xz
PHP_ASC_URL => https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.7.tar.xz.asc
PHP_SHA256 => 53558f8f24cd8ab6fa0ea252ca8198e2650160649681ce5230c1df1dc2b52faf
PHP_MD5 =>  
HOME => /root
APP_ENV => test
KERNEL_CLASS => App\Kernel
APP_AUTH_API_HOST => http://authapi
DATABASE_URL_TEST => postgresql://postgres:postgres@172.17.0.1:5433/privateapi_test
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN => ^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
$_ENV['PATH'] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/.composer/vendor/bin
$_ENV['HOSTNAME'] => fb6d372627df
$_ENV['JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN'] => 1
$_ENV['IDE_PHPUNIT_PHPUNIT_PHAR'] => /var/www/privateapi/vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-7.5-0/phpunit
$_ENV['IDE_PHPUNIT_VERSION'] => 7.5.20
$_ENV['PHPIZE_DEPS'] => autoconf        dpkg-dev dpkg       file        g++         gcc         libc-dev        make        pkgconf         re2c
$_ENV['PHP_INI_DIR'] => /usr/local/etc/php
$_ENV['PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS'] => --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --disable-cgi
$_ENV['PHP_CFLAGS'] => -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
$_ENV['PHP_CPPFLAGS'] => -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
$_ENV['PHP_LDFLAGS'] => -Wl,-O1 -pie
$_ENV['GPG_KEYS'] => 42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312
$_ENV['PHP_VERSION'] => 7.4.7
$_ENV['PHP_URL'] => https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.7.tar.xz
$_ENV['PHP_ASC_URL'] => https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.7.tar.xz.asc
$_ENV['PHP_SHA256'] => 53558f8f24cd8ab6fa0ea252ca8198e2650160649681ce5230c1df1dc2b52faf
$_ENV['PHP_MD5'] => 
$_ENV['HOME'] => /root
$_ENV['APP_ENV'] => test
$_ENV['KERNEL_CLASS'] => App\Kernel
$_ENV['APP_AUTH_API_HOST'] => http://authapi
$_ENV['DATABASE_URL_TEST'] => postgresql://postgres:postgres@172.17.0.1:5433/privateapi_test
$_ENV['CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN'] => ^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$
$_ENV['APP_SECRET'] => $ecretf0rt3st
$_ENV['DATABASE_URL'] => 
$_ENV['SYMFONY_DOTENV_VARS'] => APP_SECRET,DATABASE_URL,SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER,PANTHER_APP_ENV
$_ENV['SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER'] => 999999
$_ENV['PANTHER_APP_ENV'] => panther
$_ENV['APP_DEBUG'] => 1
```

Set Up:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- PhpStorm 2020.1.4
- Docker 19.03.12
- docker-compose 1.26.0

Comment: *"XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK=1"* and `xdebug.remote_connect_back` --  try getting rid of this (make sure it's = `0`). If `xdebug.connect_back` is enabled then `xdebug.remote_host` is ignored. It works for you for a web page debug as you have an IP there ... but for CLI debug (which is what PHPUnit is) there is no IP in request data... (P.S. This is about Xdebug connection, not about actual Xdebug extension detecting).

Comment: I would also suggest to create some fake PHPUnit test and try to debug it: get `phpinfo()` output there (Xdebug section in particular; save into a file) and see what values will be there. Maybe it somehow has different values at that moment (for some unknown yet reason)

Comment: I did the change for `connect_back`, it is still not working.
I edited the question with the phpinfo() output from phpunit

Comment: 1) Xdebug section looks OK to me -- it's there and enabled as far as I can see. Can you enable Xdebug log and try to debug (your PHPUnit tests; can try a web page as well, but make them completely separate logs) -- what will it show?

Comment: 2) Please show your PHPUnit settings from IDE -- it could be IDE misconfiguration on your end (not selecting PHP Interpreter for the project). The idea based on this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-51570#focus=Comments-27-4231759.0-0

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Your Xdebug settings look fine to me. It shows expected values for PHPUnit and it works for a web page debug.

This has to be the IDE settings / some IDE misconfiguration. In particular, **make sure that you have selected the default PHP Interpreter.** Even though you have specified one in your Run/Debug Configuration, PhpStorm still requires a project-default interpreter to be selected -- it's a know limitation: [WI-51570](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-51570).

`Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | CLI Interpreter`

[image]

**NOTE:** as of **2021.1** version the PHP settings node has been moved to the top level and now it's `Settings/Preferences | PHP | CLI Interpreter`

[image]

**P.S.** You can also set it via `File | New Projects Settings | Settings for New Projects...`. This way it will be set for all **future new projects** created on that computer (which you can then change as required on per project basis).

Comment: Setting a default CLI interpreter fixed it for me, too. Head to Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > CLI interpreter, and set whichever one you need.

Comment: Setting the project-wide default interpreter worked for me as well.

Comment: Arrived here. Discovered that I had already upvoted this answer a year ago or so. Problem still exists in 2022.1. @JetBrains how much effort can it possibly be to update your error message or show a helpful popup when clicking on it?

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem.
I fixed it by specifying the CLI Interpreter in Preferences > PHP

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will not work in your docker since the steps will be removed when running the container:

```
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN source ~/.bashrc
```

you may use:

```
ENV PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

**Update**

You may also not using the `IP` in your config, instead you can map the port to your host when starting your container.

First change `XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=172.17.0.1` to `XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=0.0.0.0`

Comment: I did the change and rebuild the image, but I have the same behaviour.

Comment: please add how you start the container ? did you setup the ports and the network correctly that your IDE can find them ?

Comment: I will add those information.
XDebug works with the browser, just not with PHPUnit.

Comment: I see your updates. I don't really get why I shall do that because I already have XDebug working, just not with PHPUnit.
I tested your update and it doesnt work better, and now if I want to use xdebug with the browser, it says me that the port 10000 is Busy (which is due to the port mapping)

Comment: *"ports:- "10000:10000""* You do not need that: It's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around. With that in place you tell Docker to use that port and now IDE is unable to listen on that port (and not able to accept incoming connections).

Comment: @LazyOne Thats also how I understand it.Yet it doesnt solve my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. However it turned out in XDebug 3 the port changed to 9003.

Ctrl + Alt + S > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug > Debug Port to **9003**